# Fixing a Null Pointer Exception in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm learning about BufferedReaders and a few other classes and am making a small program that takes a text file with information about courses I've taken and calculates my GPA. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class GradeFormatter {

    public static ArrayList<String[]> courses;
    public static double unitsAttempted;
    public static double unitsPassed;
    public static double gradePoints;
    public static double gpa;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("grades.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    processLine(line);
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist.");
        }
    }

    public static void processLine(String line) {
        String[] newCourse = line.split("\\t");
        courses.add(newCourse);
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following output when I try to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GradeFormatter.processLine(GradeFormatter.java:34)
    at GradeFormatter.main(GradeFormatter.java:23)
```

Could anyone help me out with why I'm getting this null pointer exception? I cannot seem to figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: Something is null.  The stack-trace tells you where.  Use the debugger to determine which thing is null.

Comment: You have not initialized `courses`. You're trying to add elements to a list that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should initilize the ArrayList courses `ArrayList<String[]> courses = new ArrayList<String[]>()`